# Select data with XSLT from XMI and UML tags in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, uml, xmi

I'm trying to print this XML file in an HTML table using out of XSLT and I don't know how to get the information from the XMI and UML tags, like `XMI.header` or `XMI.exporter`.

I know how to get the attributes from the root tag XMI but not the other tags under.

**XML document**

```
<XMI xmi.version="1.2"
    xmlns:UML="org.omg.xmi.namespace.UML"
    timestamp="Wed Apr 21 18:15:34 CEST 2010">

  <XMI.header>
    <XMI.documentation>
      <XMI.exporter>
        ArgoUML (using Netbeans XMI Writer version 1.0)
      </XMI.exporter>
      <XMI.exporterVersion>0.30(6) revised on $Date: 2010-01-11 22:20:14 +0100 (Mon, 11 Jan 2010) $
      </XMI.exporterVersion>
    </XMI.documentation>
    <XMI.metamodel xmi.name="UML" xmi.version="1.4"/>
  </XMI.header>

  <XMI.content>
    <UML:Multiplicity xmi.id="-64--88-0--57--53f31703:128211b208a:-8000:0000000000000DDF">
      <UML:Multiplicity.range>
    <UML:MultiplicityRange xmi.id="-64--88-0--57--53f31703:128211b208a:-8000:0000000000000DE0"
      lower="1" upper="1"/>
      </UML:Multiplicity.range>
  </XMI.content>

</XMI>

</UML:Multiplicity>
```

**XSLT code**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="XMI">
    XMI Version: <xsl:value-of select="./@xmi.version"/>
    <br/>
    Generated: <xsl:value-of select="./@timestamp"/>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's a good resource to learn XSLT http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp   . By the way, you can use select="/XMI.header/XMI.documentation/XMI.exporter" notation in a template

Comment: Your XML data is invalid. Presumably the stray `</xsl:stylesheet>` tag at the end belongs before the `</XMI.content>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMI.header` and `XMI.exporter` are just ordinary XML tag names. Within the ASCII range the initial character has to be alphanumeric or an underscore, but after that the name can include full-stops and hyphens. So just

```
<xsl:template match="XMI.header">
```

will work for you.

The `UML` names are slightly different becuase `UML` is a namespace and must be declared at the top of your XSLT stylesheet. So you need

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:UML="org.omg.xmi.namespace.UML"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

after which you can just use the name as it stands, like

```
<xsl:template match="UML:Multiplicity">
```